# Error with the IdentityKey while trying to clone entity into another Context, using EF7 (core)

Tags: c#, sqlite, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I have been looking into different solutions regarding possibilities to copy entity from one context into another.

I keep facing the following error:

> {"The instance of entity type 'Plugin.Core.Domain.Socket' cannot be
>   tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is
>   already being tracked. For new entities consider using an
>   IIdentityGenerator to generate unique key values."}

To get a copy of the existing `Socket` I am using the following method:

```
public Socket GetCopyOfSocket(Socket socket)
        {
            if (socket == null) return null;
            var newSocket = DatabaseContext.Sockets.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(s => s.SocketId == socket.SocketId);
            if (newSocket == null) return null;
            DatabaseContext.Entry(newSocket).State = EntityState.Detached;
            return newSocket;
        }
```

After this:

```
_newContext.Sockets.Add(newSocket);
```

The problem seems to be with the IdentityKey, because for example, the `newSocket` maintains its IdentityKey and if I already have existing Socket with the same **IdentityKey** on the destination `Context`, I receive the error described above.

But shouldn't the destination context automatically give the new instance of the Socket a new unique IdentityKey?

> Both Context are new instances of the same SqLite DbContext schema,
>   different files.

### Edit 1

Partial solution for the problem seems to obediently follow the sequence of `Add(newSocket)` and `SaveChanges()`

<s>However, after successfully saving entity, and after new entity received new Id and was saved into the database. I am calling custom `GetLocal()` method which gives the exact same error as above!
Error is happening on this line:</s>

```
var data = Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>().Select(e => e.Entity);
```

the error stays the same if I am replacing the previous line with:

```
var data = Context
                .ChangeTracker
                .Entries<TEntity>()
                .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Detached)
                .Select(e => e.Entity);
```

### Edit 2

(deleted many-to-many problem description, its ruled out as not to be the source of problem)

### Edit 3

After adding the copy of `newSocket`, and calling `SaveChanges()` once everything is ok ( new entity receives new ID etc. ) But, if I call `SaveChanges()` second time right after, the exception happens. ?

Is there maybe something wrong with the way I handle `dBContext` ( lifetime etc.. ) ?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment problem has disappeared after updating to [Entity Framework Core RC2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-rc2/).